# Increasing the volume of recording in Real Time of after saving it?

Tags: objective-c, speech-recognition, volume, speech

I used python to make a prototype, to increase the volume of audio signal in real time. It worked by using `new_data = audioop.mul(data, 4, 4)` where 'data' is chunks from Pyaudio in streaming.

Now, I have to apply similar in ObjectiveC, and even after searching I am unable to find it. How can it be done in Objective C? Do we have such control over data flow in Objective C and If we can't, Is there anyway that a recorded sample's volume can be increased?

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import audioop
import sys


FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 7
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME1 = sys.argv[1]
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME2 = sys.argv[2]
device_index = 2

print("----------------------record device list---------------------")
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
print(audio)
info = audio.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
        if (audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
            print ("Input Device id ", i, " - ", audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))

print("-------------------------------------------------------------")

index = int((input()))
print(type(index))
print("recording via index "+str(index))

stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,input_device_index = index,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print ("recording started")
Recordframes = []
Recordframes2= []
print(int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS))
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    new_data = audioop.mul(data, 4, 4)
    print("hshsh")
    Recordframes.append(data)
    Recordframes2.append(new_data)
# data = stream.read(CHUNK)
# print("hshsh")
# Recordframes.append(data)
# print ("recording stopped")


stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME1, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(Recordframes))
waveFile2 = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME2, 'wb')
waveFile2.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile2.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile2.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile2.writeframes(b''.join(Recordframes2))
waveFile.close()
waveFile2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVAudioEngine` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine)) to tap into the raw audio data. Alternatively, still using `AVAudioEngine`, you could add an `AVAudioUnitEQ` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiouniteq)) node to your audio graph and use that boost the gain.

Using either method, you can then write out to a file using `AVAudioFile` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiofile)).